# in `pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv` can I create a virtualenv which refers to `system`, i.e. without a `pyenv install` before?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

Hello I am using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and its plugin [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv).

Normally I would install a pyenv first (e.g. `pyenv install 3.7.6`) and then a virtualenv (e.g. `pyenv virtualenv 3.7.6 myenv`) and then proceed with `pip install`.

This time, as the system already features python 3.7, and because I am short of disk space (I'm on a Raspberry Pi 3, with `buster`), I would like to avoid installing the whole python, but still I would like to isolate in a user-space virtualenv the python packages (numpy, pandas, ecc.). So I would like to define a virtualenv that uses the system python3.

I tried `pyenv virtualenv system sysenv` but it doesn't work (it claims it can't find pip):

```
$ pyenv virtualenv system sysenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

which I don't understand, as I have both `python-pip` and `python3-pip` apt packages installed.

So: is it possible to create a virtualenv that uses the system python3? What do I miss? Or, is it a bad idea as the system python might be upgraded by apt later?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use virtualenv without pyenv.

e.g.

```
$ virtualenv -p $(which python3) sysenv
```

I can't remember if this command activates the env, so if not you can then run

```
$ source sysenv/bin/activate
```

Comment: Thanks @Hitobat, I am with `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` plugin (see links in the question), so I can't use that same command. I tried with `$ pyenv virtualenv -p system sysenv` and I get the answer `pyenv-virtualenv: 'system' is not installed in pyenv.` If I omit the `-p` option, it goes even worse: `pyenv: pip: command not found`